# Loop exit condition on fgets doesn't work

Tags: c, string, loops, fgets

I have a text file like this

```
"input"
height : 227
width : 227
depth : 3

"conv"
num_output : 96
pad : 0
kernel_size : 11
stride : 4
group : 1

"relu"

"pool"
kernel_size : 3
stride : 2
```

I'm reading it in a loop (this is partial code)

```
char line[100];

while ((fgets(line, sizeof(line), filePtr))) {
    if (line[0] != "\n") {
        sscanf(line, "%15s : %15s", tmpstr1, tmpstr2);
        printf("%s\n",  tmpstr2);
        printf("line = %s", line);
    } else
        break;
}
```

But I observed that the `if` condition always holds true and the output is as below

```
"input"
227
line = height : 227
227
line = width : 227
3
line = depth : 3
3
line = 
3
line = "conv"
96
line = num_output : 96
0
line = pad : 0
11
line = kernel_size : 11
4
line = stride : 4
1
line = group : 1
1
line = 
1
line = "relu"
1
line = 
1
line = "pool"
3
line = kernel_size : 3
2
line = stride : 2
```

I have tried comparison with `\0` as well but the result doesn't change. Please point me where I'm going wrong.

P.S. : I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit machine with gcc 5.2.1.

Comment: `line[0] != "\n"` --> `line[0] != '\n'`

Comment: You are comparing `char` with an string literal, you should turn on compiler warnings. `gcc` -pedantic -Werror

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks for pointing it out. Totally overlooked that typo.

Comment: I closed it as a duplicate for 'string comparison' but it can also be regarded as character comparison.  The condition `if (line[0] != "\n") {` compares a `char` with a `char *`.  It can be fixed by using `if (strcmp(line, "\n") != 0)` or by using `if (line[0] != '\n')` — both work in this context.  For general string comparison (longer strings), use `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newline is a character, not a string, so change this:

```
line[0] != "\n"
```

to this:

```
line[0] != '\n'
```

---

Enable compiler warnings (`-Wall` flag in GCC) and you should see something like this:

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer
warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to compare an string literal with `char`.

With:

```
if(line[0] != '\n')
```

It works well.

If you're reading from a file that's been opened in text mode (including `stdin`), then whatever representation the underlying system uses to mark the end of a line will be translated to a single '\n' character.

You should turn on compiler warnings. For `gcc` it's `-pedantic` `-Werror`.

Comment: Good answer, however check my answer for the flags (I got the warnings by using one flag only).

Comment: Yes you do, ill leave it so OP will see that there are more opportunities for `gcc` :-)

Comment: You were faster & have good answer tho so you deserve it.

Answer (score 0):

On [this site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) we can see that fgets doesn't change the value of str (line in your case). Because the value does not change, your if test keeps getting evaluated to true.

If you want to check whether fgets found the end of the file, you have to check if fgets returned NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a character to a string: `line[0] != "\n"` should produce a warning.  To detect an empty line, use this instead:

```
line[0] != '\n'
```

Note that you should also verify the return value of `sscanf()`:

```
char line[100];

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), filePtr) && *line != '\n') {
    if (sscanf(line, "%15s : %15s", tmpstr1, tmpstr2) == 2) {
        printf("%s\n",  tmpstr2);
        printf("line = %s", line);
    } else {
        printf("invalid format: %s", line);
    }
}
```